# Highslide popup to be center of parent jsp page

Tags: jsp, highslide

I have a JSP page which includes many JSP pages. Some of the JSP pages contains the Highslide popup code which works fine. But the popup opens up in the center of **THAT** JSP page not the parents.

Is there any way I can make it open relative to the parent page?

Comment: ok..I got hs.targetY and hs.targetX, for the positioning. But now I want it to be dynamically popping up. Means..if I want to scroll to some other position on page, my popup should appear to the new position. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe use [`onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) event to update it's position?

Comment: Well i used a work around for the purpose. Used jQuery to have a new UI..much more specific..but yes will try with this onscroll functionality. Will let you know!Thanks!